# How to modify the bot code to post base64 images for Teams

Tags: base64, microsoft-teams

How can we post Base64 images to Ms Teams from a bot that is pulling them from sharepoint to a QnA kb?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please have a look on [Data URIs document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and try the below sample json.

{

```
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "Image",
        "style": "Person",
        "url": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4 //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU 5ErkJggg==",
        "size": "Small"
    }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0"
```

}